# Redshift serverless charged_seconds and compute_seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I am trying to understand pricing for Redshift Serverless but slightly confused between `compute_seconds` and `charged_seconds`.

I have currently set base RPU to 128 which is the default.

I have have executed certain queries and after that have queried the `sys_serverless_usage` view and I see the below results

[image]

below are some of my questions

1. Does compute_seconds refer to the number of seconds it took for the query to execute?
2. what's the difference between `charged_seconds` and `compute_seconds`. On row 6 i see that `compute_seconds` is `0` but `charged_seconds` are `7680`.

Any help here would be great, thanks.

Comment: Charged seconds can be 0 while a transaction is still running and hasn't completed yet.

Answer (score 1):

So you are charged at **minimum for 60 seconds** of compute, that means for each time interval of 1 minute (like in the table) you will be charged `60sec * compute_capacity`

```
60 * 128 = 7680
```

So because your base RPU is set to `128` ~ when you run queries it will take the seconds that Serverless is running and multiply it by `128`

For example the 3rd row your compute seconds is `3799` and `128` rpu

```
3799 / 128  = 29.67 seconds
```

so essentially for each row you can take the `compute_capacity` and use that do derrive seconds that cluster was running `compute_seconds / compute_capacity`
and the charged_seconds is essentially showing you what you are going to be billed each minute (due to 1 minute min billing)

so at `128` RPU each minute at `0.375 Per RPU Hour` thats

```
 7680 / 3600 * 0.375 = 0.79c Per minute
```

so WHENVER you run some queries at `128` Base RPU you are going to be charged `79c` for each minute the cluster is in use, even if you run 1 query that finishes in 200ms you will be charged for the full minute, alternatively if you run 50 queries concurrently at `128` RPU and they all complete in 30secs within the same minute, you will be still only charged `79c`

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, compute would be the number of seconds to execute the query
2. Charged seconds could be rounded up based on the minimum billing of 60 seconds. 128 RPU * 60 seconds = 7680

Comment: But this doesn't explain why something like 270 compute seconds and 1108 compute seconds would both come out to 7680.

Comment: 270 compute seconds is 270/128 clock seconds. Round it up to 60 minimum seconds times 128 RPUs